# Erro ao popular Array com VueJS + Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js

Sou Dev RoR e estou em meus estudos iniciais com VueJS. Para tanto, iniciei a criação de uma TodoList com Firebase para a persistência de dados e um problema me ocorreu.

Criei um função para retornar os dados do FireBase.

https://github.com/luizpicolo/ToDo.list/blob/8e2ba8cba714a9541ef0c91cf38d4ae69ae915c7/js/database.js#L22

Logo, quando há uma alteração ou inclusão de algum dado no banco, o Firebase me retorna todos os dados que são apresentados por meio dessa instância do Vue.

https://github.com/luizpicolo/ToDo.list/blob/8e2ba8cba714a9541ef0c91cf38d4ae69ae915c7/js/main.js#L1

Porém, ao fazer a primeira  chamada da função `listTasks()`, na linha 4 no link acima, ela me retorna os dados corretamente. Mas, quando há a alteração, o vetor não é montado novamente, mas sim concatenado com os valores novos, ou seja, tenho dados duplicados.

Como faria para que, sempre quando houve dados novos ou alteração, o Vue não concatene o vetor?

Acredito que seja algo do Vue por meio de todos os testes que fiz até o momento. Mas isso é apenas um achimos inicialmente.

Comment: O que é Dev RoR?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Entendi como sendo Developer Ruby On Rails

Comment: Não edite uma questão para mostrar que foi resolvida. Ao invés disso, coloque a resolução como resposta e aceite-a.

Comment: Conforme suas orientações, o tópico foi corrigido. Obrigado pela dica  @RosárioPereiraFernandes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro era na função quer retornava os dados. Ao invés do método `on` eu utilizei o método `once`. Funcionou da forma que queria. [https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?hl=pt-br][3]

```
function listTasks(){
    var tasks = [];
    var listTasks = database.ref('tasks');
    listTasks.once('value', function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
         tasks.push(childSnapshot.val());
      });
    });

    console.log(tasks);
    return tasks;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Viva,

Parece-me que o problema está no facto do array tasks não estar a ser limpo antes de obteres os dados da base de dados.

Experimenta assim:

```
function listTasks(){
  var listTasks = database.ref('tasks');
  listTasks.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var tasks = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
       tasks.push(childSnapshot.val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Infelizmente esse não é o problema. Já havia testado essa função desta forma e nada funcionou.

Answer (score -1):

```
methods: {
  addTodoInList: function(){
    this.tasks = []
    writeTask(11, "teste 7", "12/12/2012", 'Lorem Ipsum 3');
  }
}

function listTasks(){
  var tasks = []; // REMOVA ESSA LINHA
  var listTasks = database.ref('tasks');
  listTasks.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
       tasks.push(childSnapshot.val());
    });
  });

  console.log(tasks);
  return tasks;
}
```

Comment: Respostas só com código dão muito pouco valor à comunidade. Vale lembrar que o objetivo no StackOverflowPT é não só mostrar qual o problema que existe, assim como o que fazer para ultrapassa-lo, e até quais outros possíveis obstáculos. Em suma queremos evitar os que o autores das perguntas se limitem a copiar código sem saberem o que estão a fazer.

Comment: Está certo, é que falei com o autor do tópico em outro canal, por isso só postei o código, vou corrigir isso.